# Coding a rotation in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to study the Van der Waals interactions between two benzene molécules under various configurations. To do that i have writen a bash script to rotate one of the two molecules (only around the x-axis for now) from the file containing the positions of those 2. The code seems to run without bugs but gives completely wrong results. I have checked many times and i didn't find any "mathematical" error so maybe i did a syntax error somewhere ? 
I am a beginner in bash (and linux) so any help would be appreciated :) !
Here is the code :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Angle of rotation (in rad:"
read angle
echo "File or path to file :"
read fichier
echo "Your file:"
cat $fichier
echo "Give the line numbers which contain the atoms you want to rotate :"
read ligneDebut
read ligneFin

# creation of an associative array playing the role of the rotation matrix
declare -A Rx 
Rx=([1,1]=1 [1,2]=0 [1,3]=0 [2,1]=0 [2,2]=`echo "c($angle)" | bc -l` [2,3]=`echo "-s($angle)" | bc -l` [3,1]=0 [3,2]=`echo "s($angle)" | bc -l` [3,3]=`echo "c($angle)" | bc -l`)

#storage of the atomic positions in an array
declare -A posAtomes
for((i=$ligneDebut; i<=$ligneFin; i++)) do
    for((j=1; j<4; j++)) do
        posAtomes[$i,$j]=`awk -v ligne=$i -v colonne=$j '{if(NR==ligne) print $(colonne+1)}' $fichier` 
    done
done

#computation of the new positions after rotation
declare -A newPos
for((i=$ligneDebut; i<=$ligneFin; i++)) do
    for((j=1; j<4; j++)) do
        newPos[$i,$j]=`echo "${posAtomes[$i,1]} * ${Rx[$j,1]} + ${posAtomes[$i,2]} * ${Rx[$j,2]} + ${posAtomes[$i,3]} * ${Rx[$j,3]}" | bc -l`
    done
done

#writing the new positions in the original file
for ((i=$ligneDebut; i<=$ligneFin; i++)) do
    for ((j=1;j<4;j++)) do
        awk -v ligne=$i -v colonne=$j -v val=${newPos[$i,$j]} '{if(NR==ligne) {$(colonne+1)=val; print $0} else print $0}' $fichier > tmp && mv tmp $fichier
    done
done
```

The position file looks like this (here is only one molecule) :

```
C 0.00000000000000000E+00 1.39600002765655495E+00 12.25
C 1.20899999141693093E+00 6.98000013828277699E-01 12.25
C 1.20899999141693093E+00 -6.98000013828277699E-01 12.25
C 0.00000000000000000E+00 -1.39600002765655495E+00 12.25
C -1.20899999141693093E+00 -6.98000013828277699E-01 12.25
C -1.20899999141693093E+00 6.98000013828277699E-01 12.25
H 0.00000000000000000E+00 2.47900009155273393E+00 12.25
H 2.14700007438659712E+00 1.24000000953674294E+00 12.25
H 2.14700007438659712E+00 -1.24000000953674294E+00 12.25
H 0.00000000000000000E+00 -2.47900009155273393E+00 12.25
H -2.14700007438659712E+00 -1.24000000953674294E+00 12.25
H -2.14700007438659712E+00 1.24000000953674294E+00 12.25
```

If you know what i did wrong ... thanks in advance !

Comment: Since you're saying you're a beginner in `bash`, I'll take the opportunity to advise you to use another language for that sort of task. `bash` has many advantages, but the ease of implementing arithmetic operations isn't one of them. If you're looking for a general-use language available on every linux machines, I think `python` would be a good pick. More specialized languages would include Mathematica and Matlab/Octave.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer some basic troubleshooting steps, though I am not familiar with the exact calculation.

0)  To get more detailed help, try posting the example inputs entered (what rotation angle and what line numbers), the result you expect, and the result you are seeing. Also, it may be helpful to add the formula you are attempting to implement.

1) Try adding a lot of simple echo statements to view your progress at various steps: debugging statements. For instance:

```
echo "Angle of rotation (in rad:"
read angle
echo "OK, operating with angle: "${angle}

echo "File or path to file :"
read fichier
echo "OK, input file is: "${fichier}
```

It seems to me that these two steps are correct in your program. However, hopefully the approach suggests further debugging steps for you. Add these debugging echo statements throughout your code to output the intermediate values and verify they are working as intended.

Happy hacking. Also, is there a particular reason you are implementing this with bash? Perhaps another language, for instance one with a built-in vector math library (Python, R, Matlab...), would be more suitable.

Comment: invoking the script with `bash -x` (or adding a `set -x` command in the script) is IMO an easier alternative to adding lots of `echo`, although the extremely verbose output can be offputting

Comment: That just shows you which line is running, right? I was suggesting displaying the output of each step, for instance the values of the variables. Basically step-through debugging. ;-)

Comment: it shows you which command is running, which is much closer to step-by-step because it will decompose composed commands in their multiple steps and show each successive step working with the result of the previous. I just noticed it won't work that well with `read`, but for standard variable affectation it will show the effective value of the variable instead of the expression, which has the same effect as adding an extra echo after that step.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies ! i thought i had aready done the "put echo everywhere" thing, but i didn't do it properly. I found out the mistake : bc can't handle scientific notation (for a calculator that a bit lame u_u) so one has to use sed or awk to repace all the E+01 by 10^01. Damn i lost so much time on this ! Next time i'll use Python haha